# Can't change size of view in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am using Xcode 7.3, I can change the size of any kind of view from the property and I can drag the views around. Unfortunately, view seems to be locked while trying to edit the size of view using mouse. As you can see in the image, when I click ImageView its not giving option to resize the view.

[image: Locked ImageView]

Comment: Click on image view, and 6 squares will appear on corners and mid top and bottom edges. Click on any Square and drag to size you want. It is same as you resize the size of image in Word.

Comment: @S.Jain the problem here is, 6 squares is not appearing on my screen. It seems to be locked somehow.

Comment: Delete that ImageView and try re-adding Image View from object Library

Comment: @S.Jain I did that, it didn't work. It happened when I tried to update to Xcode 8 and later changed to Xcode 7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to Editor > Canvas > Show Resize Knobs to make changes.

Comment: This is also the correct answer. Just little late :P

Answer (score 0):

Select your viewcontroller and then click Show document outline in the left bottom corner. It will show all the views in that view controller.
Then single click the item i.e, Imageview in this case. Then the 6squares will appear.

Comment: Thanks, it worked by selecting Editor > Canvas > Show Resize Knobs.